# Was cqlsh 5.0.1 broken in cassandra 3.11.2 release?

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

My OSX install of Cassandra seems to have been broken by yesterday's release. Cassandra seems to start OK.

```
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro: fractal jeremy$ cqlsh --version
cqlsh 5.0.1



Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:fractal jeremy$ cqlsh localhost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.2/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2443, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.2/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2421, in main
    encoding=options.encoding)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.2/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py", line 488, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 735, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.__init__ (cassandra/cluster.c:10935)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'no_compact'
```

Comment: This seems to run on my Mac ok.  Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7.10

Comment: bungle's answer solved this for me, exact scenario than you

Comment: I have filed a bug in Apache's JIRA issue tracker: [CASSANDRA-14301](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14301).

Answer (score 24):

I just commented this line `488`: `#no_compact=no_compact,` in file `/usr/local/Cellar/cassandra/3.11.2/libexec/bin/cqlsh.py` and it works again.

Comment: I had five references to this littered in that file, had to comment them all out and it works as well

Comment: It is line 483 for me, just installed via brew, but that worked for me as well

Comment: I just commented 3 `no_compact=False`, and `cqlsh` finally started. Thanks for help! Hoping those commented lines won't break something else…

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. My current workaround was to install [cqlsh via pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cqlsh/5.0.4), and then run Cassandra (ScyllaDB in our case) via a docker container.

You can file an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA/issues).

Answer (score 0):

csqlsh was not broken in the 3.11.2 release of Cassandra.  However, the Homebrew formula for the 3.11.2 release was originally broken, per [Homebrew issue 24977](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/24977).  Per that ticket and [CASSANDRA-14301](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14301?focusedCommentId=16392767&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16392767), Homebrew was configured to use the wrong version of the Cassandra Driver, which was using an incompatible version of Python.

This has since been fixed in Homebrew, so new installations of 3.11.2 should not have this issue.